# creating a class as a global repository for variables used in several activities of an app

Tags: android, global-variables

I would like to create one class which holds some key values of the app so I can share and access them in all activities. This is how I have done it so far:

I define a class like this:

```
public class GlobalVars {
    public static String str1;
    public static String str2;
    public static Integer int1;
    public static Integer int2;

    public static MyDBAdapter myDBAdapter;

    public static Boolean isOK1() {
        return str1.length() > 3;
    }
}
```

This is how I fill them at the start of the app:

```
private void getAllInfo() {

        // first get the info
        Cursor appCursor = cursor;

        GlobalVars.str1 = appCursor.getString(appCursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDBAdapter.KEY1));
        if (GlobalVars.str1 != null) {
        } else {
            GlobalVars.str1 = "";
        }

        GlobalVars.int1 = appCursor.getInt(appCursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDBAdapter.KEY_NUMBER1));
        if (GlobalVars.int1 != null) {
        } else {
            GlobalVars.int1 = 1;
        }
```

and I access those values normally just by writing

```
GlobalVars.int1 = ...
```

or

```
i = GlobalVars.int1;
```

wherever I need to

At the very end when the app finishes I put all the values back in the DB.

Is this the best way to handle global variables in this way?

I get really strange NullPointerException Errors when accessing the GlobalVars.int1 variable with users who got the app - while I am 100% the value is always correctly assigned and never with a null.

Do I have to allocate the GlobalVars object before using it? 
Is there any possible explanation how those values can become null without me assigning null anywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use shared preferences for configuration / shared data storage ( as long as you have reasonable amount of them - database is for potentially unlimited amount )

I work on dependency injector for preferences ( setting values from preferences works already ):
https://github.com/ko5tik/andject

As for your question about null value - if you not assign it,  it is null

Comment: At the beginning of the app I assign like this: GlobalVars.int1 = Constants.c1  where I have defined a Constants class with variables like this: public static final int c1 = 1;  Could it be because the constant is of type int and the GlobalVars.int1 is of type Integer?

Comment: int is primitive,   and always initiallized.  Integer is object type and can be null -  but thank to automatic boxing / unboxing  they can be mixed in code

Answer (score 1):

There is a concept called `SharedPreferences` in Android, which allows the storage of primitive values and to access them from every activity of your application. You can find more information here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

I think this is preferable to a class with only static variables. You might find some other interesting ideas in the API chapter about DataStorage, especially concerning your persistent database access.

And the values in your class are `null` because that's the default value for all object references. So, if you're using `Integer` rather than `int` the default value is `null`, not -- as maybe expected -- `0`.